# Convert Files/Media to a URL using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, html5-audio

NodeJS currently scans all files inside a folder and creates a JSON list.
These folders contain media files such as mp3.
I am sending a list of JSON from NodeJS containing the list of these files.

```
"data": 
{
    "wav": 
    [
        "2044197581O0140602 - zIgnacio, Ohmar.wav",
        "2044197592O0140602 - zPadua, Pawla.wav",
        "2044197599O0140602 - Freeman, Jennifer.wav",
        "2044197606O0140602 - zSinogat, Virginia.wav",
        "2044197616O0140602 - zSulit, Catherine.wav",
     ]
}
```

I need to send the file PATH also.

```
"data": 
{
"wav": 
[

  {  "filename": "2044197581O0140602 - zIgnacio, Ohmar.wav"
    "url" : "http://file location/2044197581O0140602 - zIgnacio, Ohmar.wav"
   } 
 ]
}
```

This is so that I can play these files on the browser by URIEncoding. Is this possible using NodeJS?

I am using

```
 fs.readdir(path, function(err, files1)
```

to read the files list from the folder. But I also need to send file complete PATH as a URL.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Are you asking how to make the URLs you create actually work to serve those files?  Or are you asking something related to sending this JSON?

Comment: my asking is how to make the URL.so that i can hit those URL from client side.